# How many using statements should I use? Is there a limit?

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

I have noticed that the correct way to open and close connections to a database is with the [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement because it automatically uses the [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) interface to release the resources (please correct me otherwise).

Therefore, I decided to use it, but the code started to look a bit wired after 3 nested usages.

Here's some code I was writing, it's an event handler for a button where I use the `using` statement to create some MySQL related instances that need to be disposed of once I finish the usage. Could you please tell me if I am using it correctly? Thanks in advance.

```
private void buttonAdicionar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
    {
        using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter())
        {
            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
            {
                try
                {
                    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT codigo, descricao, unidMedida, vlUnitario FROM tab_estoque WHERE codBar = @codBar;", con))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@codBar", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.textBoxCodBarras.Text;

                        con.Open();
                        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        da.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        da.Fill(dt);

                        // Caso haja alguma linha no DataSet ds então existe um produto com o codigo de barra procurado no banco de dados
                        if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
                        {
                            bool itemIgual = false;
                            int rowIndex = 0;

                            // Passa por todas as linhas do carrinho de compras para verificar se existe outro item igual
                            foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvCarrinhoRow in dataGridViewCarrinho.Rows)
                            {
                                // Verifica se o produto da linha do carrinho de compra é o mesmo do código de barras
                                if (dgvCarrinhoRow.Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString() == dt.Rows[0][0].ToString())
                                {
                                    // Verifica se estão tentando vender uma certa quantidade de um produto que esteja acima da quantidade do mesmo no estoque
                                    if (this.VerificarSeExcede(Convert.ToInt32(dgvCarrinhoRow.Cells[1].FormattedValue), Convert.ToInt32(dgvCarrinhoRow.Cells[3].FormattedValue) + 1) == 1)
                                    {
                                        // Adiciona mais um na quantidade do item no carrinho de compra
                                        dgvCarrinhoRow.Cells[3].Value = Convert.ToInt32(dgvCarrinhoRow.Cells[3].FormattedValue) + 1;
                                        // Multiplica o VL. ITEM. pela nova quantidade e armazena o resultado em VL. ITEM
                                        dgvCarrinhoRow.Cells[6].Value = String.Format("{0:f}",
                                            (Convert.ToDouble(dgvCarrinhoRow.Cells[3].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(dgvCarrinhoRow.Cells[5].Value)));

                                        // Adiciona o valor do produto ao valor total da venda
                                        this.totalVenda += Convert.ToDouble(dgvCarrinhoRow.Cells[5].Value);
                                    }
                                    else if (this.VerificarSeExcede(Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()), 1) == 0)
                                    {
                                        MessageBox.Show("Ocorreu a tentativa de vender um produto que está em falta no estoque.", "Caixa", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        MessageBox.Show("Ocorreu a tentativa de vender uma certa quantidade deste produto que excede a quantidade do mesmo no estoque.", "Caixa", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                                    }

                                    itemIgual = true; // Evita que o if abaixo seja executado
                                    break; // Sai do loop para econimizar tempo no processamento
                                }

                                rowIndex++;
                            }

                            // Caso o item não seja igual a nenhum outro no carrinho ele é adicionado
                            if (!itemIgual)
                            {
                                // Verifica se estão tentando vender uma certa quantidade de um produto que esteja acima da quantidade do mesmo no estoque
                                if (this.VerificarSeExcede(Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()), 1) == 1)
                                {
                                    this.dataGridViewCarrinho.Rows.Add(
                                        ++this.item,                     // ITEM
                                        dt.Rows[0][0],    // CÓDIGO
                                        dt.Rows[0][3],    // DESCRIÇÃO
                                        1,                          // QTD.
                                        dt.Rows[0][2],    // UN.
                                        dt.Rows[0][3],    // VL. UNIT.
                                        dt.Rows[0][3]);   // VL. ITEM.

                                    // Adiciona o valor do produto ao valor total da venda
                                    this.totalVenda += Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[0][3].ToString());
                                }
                                else if (this.VerificarSeExcede(Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()), 1) == 0)
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("Ocorreu a tentativa de vender um produto que está em falta no estoque.", "Caixa", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("Ocorreu a tentativa de vender uma certa quantidade deste produto que excede a quantidade do mesmo no estoque.", "Caixa", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                                }
                            }

                            this.AtualizarValorCompra();
                            this.dataGridViewCarrinho.ClearSelection();
                        }
                        else // Mensagem exibida caso a consulta nao retorne alguma coisa
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Este item não consta no banco de dados.", "Caixa", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Ocorreu um erro durante a comunicação com o banco de dados.\n\n" + ex.Message, "Caixa", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    this.LimparControles(1);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no set limit to how many levels of nesting you can have, with or without `using`, but of course there is a practical limit of how much nesting you can fit on screen without making your eyes hurt. To that end, it is often a good idea to limit nesting. You can do it by observing that curly braces after compound statements are optional. Therefore, you can do this:

```
using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter())
using (DataTable dt = new DataTable()) {
    ...
}
```

The statements remain nested inside each other as before, but they look "flat" on the screen.

One limitation of this approach is that all three variables (`con`, `da`, and `dt`) will be disposed at the end of the same scope. This is not a problem in this particular case, because you end all three scopes without any statements in between (i.e. you have three closing braces at the end). However, a need to end the scope of one of the variables earlier than others may force you to use an additional level of nesting.

Comment: Thanks for that information, I did't knew that I could do that!

Answer (score 2):

I tend to stack them up, a bit like this:

```
try
{
    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(...))
    using (var adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter())
    using (var table = new DataTable())
    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(...))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The thing to note is that the scope doesn't need to be surrounded by braces `{ }` if it's only a single instruction.

The same applies to `foreach` and `if` blocks:

```
foreach(var x in y) DoSomething();
```

Comment: Thanks for your information too retailcoder, but dasblinkenlight's answer looks more complete.

Comment: No problem, here I edited to add a bit more meat; the idea is that a scope doesn't _need_ the braces if it's only a single instruction.

Comment: @Zignd actually you should accept dasblinkenlight's answer, it's not only more complete, it gives you the actual reason why/when you should introduce a level of indentation; mine only tells you why you don't need one.